# Silverlight site showing - forbidden

Tags: php, silverlight

I have been asked to move a silverlight site from one host to another. I have been told that this is easy, but its not working. I was given a zip of all the files, and the database and instructions on adding a couple of mime types. We created teh db/user as per the config file.

The original site is still live, so that's good. However, all we get on the new site is 'forbidden' at every level except the root which shows (an incomplete) list.

We are 90% sure the db is set up correctly and the mime types too.

We notice that the config file is down inside www/mysite and is called _config.php - is this ok?

I am guessing that we have missed something very obvious. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It's a newby suggestion, but maybe you forgot to reset the file permissions? Try `sudo chmod 700`

If that doesn't solve the issue, then please give the complete error.

Comment: sorry to be be newbie too - where would I set this? Is it in the ftp program by setting permissions?)

Comment: the complete error is that if you go to the site all we see is the word 'forbidden'. http://c6704767.myzen.co.uk/ if we put a plain index.html file in it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after publish my Silverlight application. In my case, there was not set default document on web.config, or you can just config in IIS.